# Issue with py-solc-x library

Tags: solidity, blockchain, python, solc, py-solc-x

I don't really know what's wrong with my code or what's wrong about the way I installed and imported this library, but I just keep receiving this error and I don't really know how to handle it.
I downgraded and upgraded the version but nothing happened, same error. I will attach you the code and the error. Maybe you guys can help me with this.

```
from solcx import compile_standard, install_solc

with open("./SimpleStorage.sol", "r") as file:
    simple_storage_file = file.read()

# Compile our Solidity
print("Installing...")
install_solc('v0.4.11')

compiled_sol = compile_standard(
    {
        "language": "Solidity",
        "sources": {"SimpleStorage.sol": {"content": simple_storage_file}},
        "settings": {
            "outputSelection": {
                "*": {"*": ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.sourceMap"]}
            }
        },
    },
    solc_version="0.6.0",
)

print(compiled_sol)
```

And this is the error:

```
Installing...
solc, the solidity compiler commandline interface
Version: 0.6.0+commit.26b70077.Windows.msvc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mihigh\lesson5\web3_py_simple_storage\deploy.py", line 10, in <module>
    compiled_sol = compile_standard(
  File "C:\Users\Mihigh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\solcx\main.py", line 143, in compile_standard
    stdoutdata, stderrdata, command, proc = solc_wrapper(
  File "C:\Users\Mihigh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\solcx\utils\string.py", line 78, in inner
    return force_obj_to_text(fn(*args, **kwargs))
TypeError: solc_wrapper() got an unexpected keyword argument 'solc_version'
PS C:\Users\Mihigh\lesson5\web3_py_simple_storage>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems that you have the wrong "install_solc"
Have you tried this:

```
install_solc("0.6.0")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is coming from this line

`solc_version="0.6.0"`

Because the py-solc-x documentation says that, If not given (solc_version), the currently active version is used.
So omit this line and everything will compile properly.

The fact that you are even installing a different solc version from the one that you are specifying here
`install_solc('v0.4.11')` just makes matters .

Hope this helps.